# My graduation project ….how i can add a map zone to my android application

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

I will describe my whole project idea
First of all it’s android app
Taking about how can we attend our lecture as a university student using QR
So as a professor will generate a QR code
And as a student will use the app camera to check in the Qr code
And here is the point i want you to focus in ✨
If the student check in the QR and he is really at the university he will check without any problems
But if the situation not at the university? (For example he is at home)
The app will say “You are not at the University “and  his check in will not be counted

So the question here
How i can make a zone for the University to do that and add this to my app

I was searching about maps sdk but sadly I didn’t understand how to do it and how to add this to my app and works as my idea

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just find the GPS coordinates of the edges of your campus, and then check if their GPS coordinates are inside those bounds.  In fact it can be done easily even with a complex shape-  get the coordinate of every corner of the campus.  Create a Region object with those coordinates.  Check if their location is inside that Region.  It will have a few feet of inaccuracy at the edge of the map due to GPS being non-euclidian coordinates, but for any reasonable college campus the rounding error is less than the error in the GPS hardware.

Comment: So i should get the Latitude,Longitude for the college corner right?